# Could not cast value of type 'RealmSwift.DynamicObject' to MyCustomObject during migration

Tags: swift2, xcode7, realm, realm-migration

During `RealmSwift migration`, i want to migrate from `dynamic var customObject: CustomObject` to `let customObjectList = List<CustomObject>()`. `CustomObject` is type of `Object`

This is the chunk of code within migration

```
let newList = List<CustomObject>()
if oldObject!["customObject"] != nil {

   print(oldObject!["customObject"])                  
   var obj = oldObject!["customObject"]
   var result: CustomObject = obj as! CustomObject //Crash
   farList.append(result)
}

newObject!["customObjectList"] = newList
```

> Could not cast value of type 'RealmSwift.DynamicObject' (0x1015c82d0) to 'AppName.CustomObject' (0x1006e5550).

How do i achieve what i want? Currently what i can think of is to create a CustomObject & manually assign the values to it.

EDIT 1

I want to add a primaryKey to CustomObject. I keep getting duplicate primary key error, i'm pretty sure the key assigned is unique.

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Primary key property 'resultKey' has duplicate values after migration."

```
 migration.deleteData(CustomObject.className())

 if oldObject!["customObject"] != nil {
          let oldSubFar = oldObject!["customObject"] as! MigrationObject
          var newFarDict = oldSubFar.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(["firstName","secondName"])
          newFarDict["resultKey"] = NSUUID().UUIDString + "v1"


          let newSubFar = migration.create(CustomObject.className(), value: newFarDict )
          print(newSubFar) //its the updated object that i want
          let subFarList = newObject!["customObjectList"] as! List<MigrationObject>         

          subFarList.append(newSubFar)               

 }
```

EDIT 2

> I manage to figure out what is the error by making `resultKey` not a primary key. The app runs perfectly and when i open `.realm` to see the values, there are some fields with `""` under `resultKey` -> The duplicated primary key.  ><

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you'd like to do is like following:

Delete all `CustomObject` data if needed, because Migration List object cannot append existing objects.

Then you can enumerate `User` objects, and create each `CustomObject` from `User`'s property. And new `User` object has `customObject` property, then append the `CustomObject` object to the list.

```
migration.deleteData(CustomObject.className()) // If needed

migration.enumerate(User.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    if let oldObject = oldObject,
        let newObject = newObject {
            let oldCustomObject = oldObject["customObject"] as! MigrationObject
            let newCustomObject = migration.create(CustomObject.className(), value: oldCustomObject)

            let customObjectList = newObject["customObjectList"] as! List<MigrationObject>
            customObjectList.append(newCustomObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i modify `MigrationObject`? lets say if i want to add in new values

Comment: Use `migration.create()` to add new object. Use subscript like `newCustomObject["name"] = "..." ` or pass the value as parameter of `create()` method to add new values. Could I answer you question? If not, can you please post more details as new question?